# Installing glibc static from source

Tags: environment-variables, glibc

I need to install glibc static from source (I'm working on a server where I don't have root access) and I'm having some difficulties.

I downloaded the `glibc-2.24.tar.gz` from the [GNU FTP](https://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/glibc/), unpacked it and ran `./configure` from another directory, as indicated in the instructions. I got the following message:

```
configure: WARNING:
*** These auxiliary programs are missing or incompatible versions: makeinfo
*** some features will be disabled.
*** Check the INSTALL file for required versions.
checking LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable... contains current directory
configure: error: 
*** LD_LIBRARY_PATH shouldn't contain the current directory when
*** building glibc. Please change the environment variable
*** and run configure again.
```

First, should I bother about `makeinfo`? Second and more important, I don't understand the error concerning LD_LIBRARY_PATH. The path is not in this variable:

```
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
:/usr/local/cuda/lib64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First, should I bother about makeinfo?

Only if you want `configure` to actually work. (By the way, your entire goal: "install glibc static from source" is likely based on incorrect assumptions and you probably shouldn't be attempting that).

> Second and more important, I don't understand the error concerning LD_LIBRARY_PATH. The path is not in this variable:

```
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
:/usr/local/cuda/lib64
```

That leading empty string before `:` is equivalent to `.`, i.e. it's the same as having `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/usr/local/cuda/lib64` and the warning is correct.

Comment: Thanks, but why do you think I shouldn't install glibc from source?

Comment: @erickrf There is nothing wrong with installing GLIBC from source, if you know what you are doing. But installing it incorrectly is a fast way to render your system unbootable (make sure you have a recovery disk and know how to use it). It's the **static** part that probably should not be attempted -- there are complications, and in particular (counter-intuitively) most statically-linked programs require matching *dynamic* GLIBC version to run correctly.

Comment: I see, but I'm compiling it inside my home folder, since I don't have root access to this server.